# Can not find unit-go child process in nginx unit, curl request timeout

Tags: nginx

When I use the nginx/unit project as my LoadBalancer component, I want use golang programming language to make a plugin tool. According to the [official document](https://unit.nginx.org/installation/), I `config/make` unit source code and `go build` my program, then use `http put` command to update the config:

```
{
    "listeners": {
        "*:8500": {
            "application": "go_chat_app"
        }
    },

    "applications": {
        "go_chat_app": {
            "type": "go",
            "working_directory": "/tmp",
            "executable": "/tmp/unit-go"
        }
    }
}

#curl -X PUT -d @go.json --unix-socket /var/run/control.unit.sock http://localhost/
```

After start unit service, I can't see the unit-go child process in `ps` commond, but I see the `8500` port is listing by `unit router` process:

```
#netstat -anpt | grep 8500
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8500            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12798/unit: router


#ps auxf 
root     12795  0.0  0.0  16224   952 ?        Ss   5月25   0:00 unit: main [/usr/sbin/unitd --log /var/log/unitd.log --pid /run/unitd.pid]
nobody   12797  0.0  0.0  26468   976 ?        S    5月25   0:00  \_ unit: controller
nobody   12798  0.0  0.0 174076   932 ?        Sl   5月25   0:00  \_ unit: router
```

Anybody has same problem?

Comment: When I curl localhost:8500, it returns "Read header timeout" error.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved by [mar0x](https://github.com/mar0x), I may be using a different unitd bianary and using a new version source code, here is the `hello world` example step-by-step writen by mar0x:

```
$ cd $HOME 
$ script $HOME/unit-i126.log $ rm -rf $HOME/unit-i126 && mkdir -p $HOME/unit-i126/src
$ cd $HOME/unit-i126/src
$ git clone https://github.com/nginx/unit.git
$ cp unit/pkg/rpm/rpmbuild/SOURCES/unit.example-go-app ../go-app.go
$ cp unit/pkg/rpm/rpmbuild/SOURCES/unit.example-go-config ../go-app.json
$ cd unit
$ export GOPATH=$HOME/unit-i126
$ ./configure
$ ./configure go
$ make -s all
$ make go-install
$ ./build/unitd
$ cd $HOME/unit-i126
$ go build go-app.go
$ cp go-app /tmp/
$ curl -X PUT -d @go-app.json --unix-socket src/unit/control.unit.sock http://localhost/
$ curl http://localhost:8500/
$ kill `cat src/unit/unit.pid`
$ exit
```